# How do I initiate a jQuery plugin (sequence.js) on a DOM element that will be loaded via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sequence.js is fired via the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        autoPlay: false,
        nextButton: true,
        prevButton: true
    };

    var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
})
```

The last line identified the DOM element, obviously.  However, I am making a page where #sequence is loaded via AJAX.  Therefore, it doesn't exist when the above code is run.

I've looked in to .on() but couldn't figure out how to apply it to this scenario.

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a:not([href^='http://'])").click(function(e){

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#bigNames").offset().top
        }, 1500);


        var url = $(this).attr("href") + " #cont";

        $('#subContent').fadeOut('slow', function() {

            $('#subContent').load(url, function() {


                var contentHeight = $("#subContent").height();

                $('#bodyContent').animate({
                    height: contentHeight
                }, 'slow', function() {
                    $('#subContent').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');

                }); // close animate

                var options = {
                    autoPlay: false,
                    nextButton: true,
                    prevButton: true
                };


                var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");
            }); // close load
        }); // close fadeout

        return false;
    }); 

    $.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 30;

    $('#chad').waypoint({
       offset: 50
    });

    $('#bigNames').waypoint({
       offset: 5
    });

    $('#chad').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('#smallNames').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
        }
        else {
            $('#smallNames').animate({"opacity": "1"}, 300);
        }
    });



    $('#bigNames').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('#main').css("position", "fixed");
            $('#main').addClass("afixed");
            /* $('#main .span12').animate({"height" : "420"}, "slow", function() { */


                $(this).append('<ul id="subDateAndLoc"><li id="subDate">July 13, 2013</li><li id="subLoc">Greensburg, PA</li></ul>');
                $('#subDateAndLoc').fadeIn("slow");
            /* }); 
            $('#nav').animate({"top" : "112"}, "slow"); */

            $('#bodyContent').css("marginTop", "355px");

        }
        else {
            $('#main').css("position", "relative");
            $('#main').removeClass("afixed");
            /* $('#main .span12').animate({"height" : "500"}, "slow");
            $('#nav').animate({"top" : "160"}, "slow"); */
            $('#bodyContent').css("marginTop", "0px");
            $('#subDateAndLoc').fadeOut("500");
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });







});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [apply plugin to a new element in the DOM (jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926673/apply-plugin-to-a-new-element-in-the-dom-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You should do this the `success` callback function in your ajax method. For instance:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
      // activate your plugin here
  }
});
```

Comment: I am using the jQuery .load() function so I had to apply your idea to my scenario.  I placed the plugin activation lines in a function that runs once the .load() has finished.

That seems to get it running (the plugins preloader gif appears and it is only referenced in the external js file).  However, the plugin doesn't work.  It never loads.  It seems as if the sequence.js file (which was loaded in the head) is also referencing items that didn't exist when it was loaded.

Do I need to load the external JS file after the .load() function has finished?

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation for .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) to see how to apply callback functions. Without more of your code, it's impossible to help you further.