# Twitter Bootsrap: Popover and Auto Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Boostrap with a website re-design, and I need some jQuery help. I'm using the 'Popover' add-on that is packaged with bootstrap, and I have it in a #div tag (#onlinedata to be specific), and I'm using jquery to reload the div every 10 seconds. This works fine, however, if you happen to be hovering over the link that activates the popover when the div refreshes, the popover gets stuck.

I'm using this code for the refresh:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $("#onlinedata").load("http://website.com #onlinedata");
}, 10000);
```

And if needed, the code that activates the popover:

```
$(function () {
        $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
            placement:'right',
            title:'Title',
            content: $('#div-that-contains-data').html()
        });
});
```

Is there a way to avoid the popover from being stuck open when the div reloads?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

***Associated HTML***

The **`$id`** is a key specific for each popover because I have multiple popovers.

The popover portion which is hidden until the `popover_controller` is hovered:

```
<div id="controller_popup_$id" style="display:none;">
   <div style="font-size:11px">
       //data_fetched_from_database
   </div>
</div>
```

The link that triggers the popover

```
<li><a href="#" rel="popover_controller_$id">Link Title</a></li>
```

And finally, the current javascript I'm using (it gets looped through the database records so each record gets the following javascript):

```
$(function () {
    $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').popover({
          placement:'right',
          title:'Title (this is fetched from the database for each popover)',
          content: $('#controller_popup_$id).html()
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    // refreshing code
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#controller_popup_$id').hide(); // close any open popovers
        // fetch new html
        $('#onlinedata').load('http://website-link.com #onlinedata', function() {
            // after load, set up new popovers
            $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').popover({
                placement:'right',
                title:'Title (this is fetched from the database for each popover)',
                content: $('#controller_popup_$id').html()
            });
        });
    }, 10000); // 10 second wait
});
```

---

## **New Code Witch Semi-Works**

I'm using the following code which semi-works. The only problem I'm having is after it reloads the #onlinedata div, it multiplies the popover links.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').popover({
            placement:'right',
            title:'Title',
            content: $('#controller_popup_$id').html()
        });
        // refreshing code
        setInterval(function() {
            // fetch new html
            $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').load('http://websiteurl.com/ #onlinedata', function() {

                $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').popover('destroy'); // remove old popovers
                // after load, set up new popovers
                $('a[rel=popover_controller_$id]').popover({
                    placement:'right',
                    title:'Title',
                    content: $('#controller_popup_$id').html()
                });

            });
        }, 10000); // 10 second wait
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926673/apply-plugin-to-a-new-element-in-the-dom-jquery), I think you will need to reapply the plugin to the new DOM elements that have been `load`-ed. This effectively means adding a copy of the `popover` code after the `load` call. If old popovers are hanging around, you may have to hide them. This gives us:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // refreshing code
    setInterval(function() {
        $('a[rel=popover]').popover('destroy'); // remove old popovers
        // fetch new html
        $('#onlinedata').load('/onlinedata.html #onlinedata', function() {
            // after load, set up new popovers
            $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
                placement:'right',
                content: $('#div-that-contains-data').html()
            });
        });
    }, 10000); // 10 second wait
});
```

Comment: So something like this: http://pastie.org/private/pzwohcftawuhqttpc3ftga

If so, it didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I have this now, but it's still getting stuck: http://pastie.org/private/0ebgb0volb8ieztpznvpa

Comment: Okay, I tried your updated code, and it semi-works...I can hover over the link again and it just shows a new popover over the old one (the old one doesn't close).

Comment: Ok, I think we'll need to see the associated html that you are using.

Comment: I've updated my original post and included the associated html and what not.

Comment: Gave your updated code a try, but it's still not working as I'd like it to. Now, after 10 seconds, the popover goes away and if you hover over it again, it won't popup unless you refresh the page. Additionally, I ran the debug console in Chrome and there are no errors that show up either.

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the code I'm now using which _almost_ works. The only problem is after the .load() is requested, the popover links multiply. I'm thinking it has something to do with my php loop...

Comment: Update: don't think it's a loop issue as I tried it with just one popover and it still multiplies.